# Can PuTTY be configured to display the following UTF-8 characters?

Tags: putty, encoding, utf-8, unicode

I'd like to be able to render the characters as seen in this tweet:

[image]

I saved the tweet's JSON data and wrote a one-liner python script for testing.

```
python -c 'import json,urllib; print json.load(urllib.urlopen("http://c.sente.cc/BUCq/tweet.json"))["text"]'
```

This next image shows the output of this command on two different putty sessions, one with `Bitstream Vera Sans Mono` font and the other is using `Courier New`:

[image]

Next is an example of correct output (I wasn't using PuTTY):

[image: Correct Unicode Output]

The original JSON is at [this link using Twitter's API](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=177254367794180097&include_entities=true).

How can I get PuTTY to display those characters?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bitstream Vera Sans Mono [does not support the Chess Symbols section of UTF8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/bitstream_vera_sans_mono/list.htm). Courier New also [does not currently support the Chess Symbols section of UTF8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/courier_new/list.htm). You'll have to find a Unicode font that supports chess symbols.

Consider [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/dejavu_sans_mono/list.htm) which is Bitsream Vera Sans Mono, just with more unicode characters (including the chess symbols). FYI, [these are the unicode Codepoints for the chess symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode) which will make your search for a suitable font easier.

Once you have chosen a font you'll need to make sure that PuTTY itself is set to receive UTF-8 symbols:

1. In a PuTTy window, click the PuTTY logo in the upper left corner
2. Click "Change settings"
3. Choose which session you want to set a character set for in the "Saved Sessions" area
4. Choose "Window / Translation"
5. Choose the option "Received data assumed to be in which character set: UTF-8"

Comment: Bitstream Vera is, like, dead.

Comment: The last options is no more on Putty, could you, kindly, update the answer?